# Monitor a specific port with Performance Counter

Tags: c#, performancecounter

Is there any way I can use Performance Counter to monitor all the traffic, but in a specific port?

I am doing:

```
GetCounterValue(_netRecvCounters[index], "Network Interface", "Bytes Received/sec", _instanceNames[index]):

double GetCounterValue(PerformanceCounter pc, string categoryName, string counterName, string instanceName)
    {
        pc.CategoryName = categoryName;
        pc.CounterName = counterName;
        pc.InstanceName = instanceName;
        return pc.NextValue();  
    }
```

But it seems to log everything

Answer (score 0):

With performance counters, somebody has to explicitly provide each counter value to the registry. If nobody is providing the specific value you are looking for as input, then there is no way to get it out.

Comment: how can I do that without performance counters? Is there any other way?